# MATLAB: create checkboxes and their callbacks in a loop for

Tags: matlab, for-loop, checkbox, callback

I would like to create a gui which reads all the files (the number of files changes for each case (ii)) in a folder, then the number of files (ii) creates ii checkboxes. If a checkbox is activated, the matching file is displayed on a graph.

My issue is to create the callback in the loop for:

```
function main


N=500;
M=300;

handles.fig=figure('Units', 'Pixels','Position',[100 100 N M]);

handles.axes=axes('Units', 'Pixels','Position',[25 25 N-200 M-50]);

for ii=1:4; %input exemple

handles.check{ii}=uicontrol('style','checkbox','string','Display','position',[N-150-ii*20 M/2 150 50]);

set(handles.check{ii},'Callback',{@checkbox_callback(ii), handles});
end
end

for ii=1:4;

function checkbox_callback(ii)(gcf, event_data, handles)
val=get(handles.check(ii),'Value');
if val
    x=1:10;
    y=1:10;
    plot(x,y)
else
    grid off;
end
end
end
```

Comment: I'm not sure to get the problem. In your example you wish to create 4 checkboxes and then plot 4 graphs on the same figure if they are all checked? Can you be more specific? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You actually need just one `callback` for the `checkboxes`.

Since you are creating your GUI "programmatically" (that is not with `GUIDE`) you can modify your code as follows:

**creation of the `figure`**

change the code for the creation of the axes as follows

```
handles.axes=axes('Units', 'Pixels','tag','axes_tag','Position',[25 25 N-200 M-50]);
```

that is define the property `tag`, you will use it in the `checkbox callaback`; the `tag` of a `uicontrol` might be used with the function `findobj` to access to that `uicontrol`

change the defionition of the checkbox as follows

```
   handles.check{ii}=uicontrol('style','checkbox','string', ...
      ['Display_file_' num2str(ii)],'tag',['c_b_' num2str(ii)], ...
      'position',[N-150 M/2-ii*20 100 25],'callback','plot_sel_cb(handles.axes)');
```

that is:

- define the `tag` property: since you are i a loop you can define different tags by converting the current loop index into a string
- modify the `string` property in order to have different string for each checkbos (this is not stricly necessary)
- define the `callback` and set the axes handles as input parameter

**Definition of the checkbox callback**

- use `gcbo` in the function `get` to access to the properties of the uicontrols (`gcbo` returns the handle of the uicontrol whos callback has been called - gcbo ==> get callback object)

Within the single callback, you might identify the checkbox that has been activated by also using the properties `tag`

In the following you can finde the script for the generation of the GUI  window and the checkbox calback.

I've have modified the definitioin of the callback in order to plot different curves according to the selected checkbox.

**GUI window**

```
N=500;
M=300;

handles.fig=figure('Units', 'Pixels','Position',[100 100 N M]);

handles.axes=axes('Units', 'Pixels','tag','axes_tag','Position',[25 25 N-200 M-50]);

for ii=1:4; %input exemple

   handles.check{ii}=uicontrol('style','checkbox','string', ...
      ['Display_file_' num2str(ii)],'tag',['c_b_' num2str(ii)], ...
      'position',[N-150 M/2-ii*20 100 25],'callback','plot_sel_cb(handles.axes)');
end
```

**checkbox callback**

```
function plot_sel_cb(ax_h)
cb_id=get(gcbo,'string')
cb_pos=get(gcbo,'position')
val=get(gcbo,'value')
axes(ax_h)
hold on

if val
   x=1:10;
   y=[1:10];
   plot(x,y*cb_pos(2)/100)
   grid on
else
   grid off;
end
end
```

[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you il_raffa ! I am starting uicontrol and your detailed explanation does help. ;)